# Trigger my macro code when user enables macros in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

As macros are disabled by default (enabling them by default is not an option) whenever I open my excel worksheet containing macros I get a popup asking if I want to enable macros. Is it possible to catch the 'OK' button press event of this popup and run a macro.

I.e. if the user chooses to enable macros then my macro should run in response to that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly and regarding your "enabling them by default is not an option" statement, bear in mind that this is not necessarily true. The user can allow all the macros to be automatically executed without any prompt (under the `Developer tab`, `Macro security`, select "Enable all macros (not recommended...)"). In case of not having the macros enabled by default, you cannot do anything before the user allows the given macro to run. Once the macro is running, you have various events being automatically triggered right at the start, where you can put your code. For example: in the file `ThisWorkbook` (under "Microsoft Excel Objects"), you can use the `Workbook_Open` method. Sample code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "This is the soonest I can popup"
End Sub
```

If you copy this code in the aforementioned file, you would see a popup appearing right after the macros has been enabled.

**NOTE:** the fact of having its own file type (.xlsm) should be indicative enough. Unfortunately, quite a few people think that macros have very limited functionalities (mainly restricted to the given spreadsheet), what is a dangerous misconcepcion: a macro can do virtually the same things than a conventional .exe file.

Comment: to contradict the OPs theory about not being able to enable macros by default - it's worth reading about about a [digitally signing projects](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/digitally-sign-a-macro-project-HA001231781.aspx)

Comment: @mehow or he might simply take a look at my computer (which has this configuration :)). Actually, the fact of having to be included in specific files (.xlsm) does already represent a clear enough warning. Pleople tend to think that macros can do just a couple of things (on the specific spreadsheet) and this is a pretty dangerous misconception: a macro can do virtually the same things than a conventional .exe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Sorry to clarify my question I don't mean that macros can't be enabled by default in general I mean they won't be enabled by default on the computer I'm working on (and this is not my choice). I am aware that I can trigger macros on events in general but I don't see an event that matches this specific scenario so that's why I was asking if there is any way to catch the button press of that specific popup. Thanks again.

Comment: @db579 No problem. I did just make this point clear in order to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @varocarbas +1/I'd suggest you add your excellent comment to the vba wiki which isn't too much documented yet ... as a general warning for newbies

Comment: @d-stroyer thanks. I haven't ever done that; will take a look in a couple of hours.

Comment: @d-stroyer I have converted it into community wiki as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks the Workbook_Open event did exactly what I wanted!